# Stored Procedure in mysql phpmyadmin #1064

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to write a stored procedure in Mysql in phpmyadmin and I encountered an error:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS USP_SwitchTable //
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_SwitchTable(IN idTable1 INT, IN idTable2 INT)
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE idFirstBill INT;
    DECLARE idSecondBill INT;
    SELECT idFirstBill = id FROM bill WHERE id_table = idTable1 AND status = 0;
    SELECT idSecondBill = id FROM bill WHERE id_table = idTable2 AND status = 0;

    IF (idFirstBill IS NULL)
    BEGIN
    INSERT bill (id_table, bill_maker, status) VALLUES (idTable1, 1, 0);
    SELECT idFirstBill = MAX(id) FROM bill WHERE id_table = idTable1 AND status = 0;
    END


    IF (idSecondBill  IS NULL)
    BEGIN
    INSERT bill (id_table, bill_maker, status) VALLUES (idTable2, 1, 0);
    SELECT idSecondBill = MAX(id) FROM bill WHERE id_table = idTable2 AND status = 0;
    END

    SELECT id INTO IDBillInfoTable FROM bill_info WHERE id_bill = idSecondBill;

    UPDATE bill_info SET id_bill = idSecondBill WHERE id_bill = idFirstBill;

    UPDATE bill_info SET id_bill = idFirstBill WHERE id IN (SELECT * FROM IDBillInfoTable);

    DROP TABLE IDBillInfoTable;

END//
DELIMITER ;
```

And here's what it said :

> Error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN INSERT bill (id_table, bill_maker, status) VALLUES (idTable1, 1, 0);' at line 9

What can I do to solve the problem? I'm kinda new to this, thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL IF-clause uses `THEN` `END IF` instead of `BEGIN` and `END`.

You also might want to use temporary table for the `IDBillInfoTable` so it works with concurrent use.

```
IF (idSecondBill  IS NULL) THEN
  INSERT INTO bill (id_table, bill_maker, status) 
  VALUES (idTable2, 1, 0);

  SELECT MAX(id) into idSecondBill
  FROM bill 
  WHERE id_table = idTable2 AND status = 0;
END IF;
```

and temporary table creation:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IDBillInfoTable AS 
SELECT id
FROM bill_info 
WHERE id_bill = idSecondBill;
```

and dropping the temp table

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IDBillInfoTable;
```